# Git push triggers a rebase locally?

Tags: git, github, merge

So I'm currently using the Github for Windows tool, but I think that this is generally true for git.

I have two branches in my git repo, `master` and `development`. The repo is also on github.com, so I am getting some of the information below from there.

Naturally, I have made a bunch of changes in the `development` branch, everything checks out, so I want to sync it back up to the master.

I have the development branch already synced up to the remote development branch. On github, I look at the branches screen and it shows that `development` is 85 commits ahead of master and behind by 0. Which I figure is good, this should be an easy fast-forward merge.

I merge to master locally without any problem. It merges without conflict.

However, when I go to push to the remote github server, my git client has an issue and ends up rebasing. As I work through the rebase I have merge conflicts almost every commit.

Where do these conflicts come from? Master was already merged with development fine on my local machine. I was already up to date with the remote. There should not be anything to merge; it should just be adding my commits on top of the remote branch.

Is there a simple way to handle this "conflict" since my local should be correct in this case.

(Also, this is a private repo, that I can guarantee I'm the only one using or accessing at this time, so forcing things to match locally would be acceptable.)

Comment: "my git client has an issue and ends up rebasing" --- git **does not** perform rebase automatically.

Comment: Interesting. So it must be something happening behind the scenes of the Github for Windows client. Because when I click the "sync" button, it forces me to open a shell, which is then in the middle of rebasing.

Comment: well, if you want to ask something about git - use `git.exe`. Otherwise state it explicitly that you use another non-standard client. Protip: it's significantly less chance to get an answer if your question will be specifically about `github for windows` not `git` in general

Comment: are you absolutely sure that your local `master` and the github `master` are identical?

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I figured that something weird was happening with the sync button. Turns out that it is running the following: `git pull --rebase` and then `git push origin <branch>`, hence why a rebase was getting triggered.